# Action in SnackBar called instantly when show

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar

I'm trying to show my SnackBar but my action is being called instantly when shown and not when the button is clicked. Why is this happening?

```
fun showSnackBar(msg:String,btnMsg:String,action:Unit){
   SnackBar.make(binding.root,msg,Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
   .setAction(btnMsg){
      action
   }
}.show()
```

And thats what I do when calling this method:

```
showSnackBar("Added","Undo",undoAction())

fun undoAction(){
  //here I delete an item from a list
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is trigger right away because you are executing your method and giving the result to the method `showSnackBar`.

You must change your parameter from `Unit` to a `Callback`.

```kotlin
fun showSnackBar(..., onActionClicked: () -> Unit){
   snackbar.setAction(btnMsg) { onActionClicked() }
}
```

```kotlin
showSnackBar("Added", "Undo"){ 
  // here I delete an item from a list
}
```

or

```kotlin
showSnackBar("Added", "Undo") { undoAction() }

fun undoAction(){
  // here I delete an item from a list
}
```

or

```
showSnackBar("Added", "Undo", ::undoAction)

fun undoAction() {
  // here I delete an item from a list
}
```